# Preserve name of file using cURL to transfer files

Tags: php, http, file, curl

```
I'm transferring files from an existing http request using cURL like so...

    $postargs = array(
    'nonfilefield' =>'nonfilevalue',           
    'fileentry' => '@'.$_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'][0]
 );

 $ch = curl_init('http://localhost/curl/rec.php');
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");  
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postargs);
 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

The only way I can get this to work is using the tmp_name, without this it won't send. However, I then lose the name value for when I want to name the file later.

Is there some way to do this preserving the $_FILES array as it normally would be without curl? I'm also using an array of file fields in my script, so at the moment I have to convert my multidimensional array into a single dimension for this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename the file to it's original name using [**move_uploded_file()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

```
move_uploded_file($_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'][0], $your_uploads_dir.'/'.$_FILES['thefile']['name'][0]);
$postargs = array(
'nonfilefield' =>'nonfilevalue',           
'fileentry' => '@'.$your_uploads_dir.'/'.$_FILES['thefile']['name'][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, this will suffice...

```
    $postargs = array(
        'nonfilefield'=>'nonfilevalue',                     
        $_FILES['thefile']['name'][0] => '@'.$_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'][0]
    );
```